# What is the assurance that a magnetic monopole (if created) can be detected through the MoEDAL Experiment?

Tags: magnetic-monopoles

Please refer to this paper (http://web.mit.edu/ellisk/www/monopoles.pdf). It says in the Section B,

... One search technique relies upon the fact that, just as an electric current produces a circulating magnetic field, a magnetic current produces a circulating electric field; see equation (1). If a magnetic monopole were to pass through a conducting ring, there would be an induced current from the circulating E~ field. This current would be qualitatively different from that of an ordinary magnetic dipole passing through a conducting ring.

1. How can we differentiate the effects created due to passing of 
   (i)a monopole, 
   (ii)a dipole, 
   (iii)a pair of N and S poles (passing one by one along the same path) and 
   (iv)a stream of monopoles (mixed with N and S poles)?

The circular track through which the proton beams are accelerated contains more than 1,000 very powerful magnets.

2. What if these magnets can exert enough force to extract a monopole even before the beams collide?
3. Does the Plastic NTD technique ensures that no other particle will get trapped by the detector?
4. Is there any external magnetic field applied to direct the monopoles towards the detector?